# verifying a IF condition always AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm a beginner in AS3 so please if possible to give a point for a noob as answer. I want to have a specific button that is clicked to create a line, for example I click the button then I need to click twice on the stage

- I click it and it is selected
- I click first time on the stage to select the starting point of the line
- I click second time on the stage to select the finishing point.

I tried to do it but i can`t manage to, if it is possible please help me. This is the code i wrote

```
dr_line.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,drawln);
var test:Boolean;

function drawln(e:MouseEvent):void{
    test=true;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,reportClick);   
}

var sx,sy,fx,fy:int;
var j:int;
function reportClick(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    j=0;
    j++;

    if (test==true && j==1) {
        sx=event.localX;
        sy=event.localY;    
    }
    j++;
    test=true;
    trace(j);
    trace(test);
    if (test==true && j==2) {
        fx=event.localX;
        fy=event.localY;
        j=0;
        test=false;
        var  line:Shape = new Shape();
        line.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
        line.graphics.moveTo(sx,sy);
        line.graphics.lineTo(fx,fy);

        this.addChild(line);    
    }
}
```

How should i make it so this will work .. please help me , Thanks !!!! ,and yes the function reportClick should always be checked .... but i can`t get it going or when i press the dr_line button it should be active so it will be checked ....

Comment: We do not write code on demand! What we do is helping you doing it yourself. So please rewrite your questions and show us what you have tried so far for every single step.

Comment: What happens? Do you get the traces? Or does the click event not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning j=0 in click handler... you should do that in drawLn instead. Also, you require only one j++ in click handler.

But a cleaner approach would be to have two click listener `point1ClickListener` and `point2ClickListener`. You should attach to `point1ClickListener` in `drawLn`. Then inside `point1ClickListener` remove listening clicks to `point1ClickListener` and attach a click listener for `point2ClickListener`. Again, when `point2ClickListener` gets called remove listening for clicks to `point2ClickListner`.